# SQL highlighting in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

Files with a .SQL extension when opened in Visual Studio 2008 have T-SQL syntax highlighting.

How can I persuade the editor to apply this syntax highlighting to files with a different extension (in my case, .PLPGSQL).

The SQL editor doesn't appear to be an option in the Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension > Editor drop down list - and this is the only area of the options where I can see anything like what I'm after.

I feel like I'm missing something that should be really obvious.

Comment: I am sure there is an option to do that. Bit IIRC it is in an obscure place.

Comment: A note for anyone with VS 2010 or 2012. If you also install SQL Server Data Tools, you'll get an option for "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor" in that dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you now have your answer, but anyway for those who would still search ...

You have to fiddle a bit with your registry, at least in VS 2008:

First, create a key for your specific extension in "File Extensions"
(in my exemple: .prc)

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\File Extensions\.prc
```

Then set the default value to:
"`{FA6E5E79-C8EE-4D37-B79A-5067F8BD5630}`"

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The registry location will be different depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system.

For a 32-bit Windows installation, use:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\File Extensions

And for a 64-bit Windows installation, use:
(64-bit) HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\File Extensions

As @David indicate, you then should create a new key for your extension (like .tab, .prc, etc.) and set the default value to "{FA6E5E79-C8EE-4D37-B79A-5067F8BD5630}".